# How to separate one .jpeg file into several original ones?

Tags: bash, jpeg

So, I was messing around with bash, and accidentaly merged several .jpg files that had .txt extension into one .jpg. The stupidity I wrote was

```
mv ./*.txt .jpg
```

Any ideas on how I could undo it? the file created has a size that's compatible with the size of the other files all merged so I guess it's all there, but can't figure how to separate the binary...

(yes, why on earth did I do it? who the hell knows)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Funny I try to reproduce it and I get the error `mv: target ‘.jpg’ is not a directory`

Comment: Yeah, `mv` *can't* do that!

Comment: `cat *.txt > file.jpg` *could* do that, but by accident?

Comment: it was with mv. perhaps I put some additional slash or dot somewhere, but it was mv because I lost the originals.

Comment: Well, it seems that the other files are not concatenated on the other one after all.. they question is, where did mv sent them? :s

Answer (score 4):

JPEG files start with `d8ff` as a JPEG marker. So, hex dump your file and grep for `d8ff`:

```
 od -x yourTextfile.txt | grep d8ff
```

Then get the byte offsets, and use `dd` to extract the files. So, if a JPEG marker is seen at address 2048, do this:

```
dd if=yourTextFile bs=1 iseek=2048 > file1.jpg
```

You will need to set the blocksize to 1 (`bs=1`) to make the offset work in bytes rather than 512 byte blocks. Some `dd` versions prefer `skip` over `iseek`.

**Note**: You will get extraneous junk at the end of the JPEG file, but most image editors will ignore it.

**Updated**

Here is a slightly prettier way to recover the files in Perl...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $contents;
my $i=0;

# Slurp entire file
{
  local $/ = undef;
  open FILE, "file.txt" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
  $contents = <FILE>;
  close FILE;
}
while((my $offset=index($contents,"\xff\xd8"))!=-1){
    my $filename=sprintf("recovered_%d.jpg",$i++);
    printf "Recovering at offset: $offset into file: $filename\n";
    open(OUTFILE,">$filename");
    print OUTFILE substr($contents,$offset,10000000);
    close(OUTFILE);
    substr($contents,$offset,2)="\x00\x00";   # Overwrite this header so we find another next time
}
```

**Uglier shell version**:

You can code it something like this - quick and dirty code warning!!!

```
#!/bin/bash
file=file.txt       # Edit with the name of your text file with all JPEGs in it
n=0
od -Ad -b "$file" | \
   awk '/377 330 377 340/ {for(i=2;i<NF-4;i++)
                              if($i=="377" && $(i+1)=="330" && $(i+2)=="377" && $(i+3)=="340")
                                print $1+i-2
                          }' | \
   while read offset; do
      name="recovered_${n}.jpg"
      echo Possible JPEG at offset $offset - recovering following 10MB as $name
      dd if="$file" of="$name" bs=1 iseek=$offset count=10000000
      ((n++))
   done
```

If you are unlucky, an image's header may span across two lines of the output of `od` and in that case the `377 330 377 340` will not all be on the same line and the script will not find that image. Rather than code around this, I would suggest you run the script once and copy all the recovered files to another directory (to save them) then run it again, but after adding 4 or more bytes to the start of the file in order to force the entire JPEG signature onto the next line like this:

```
(echo spacer; cat file.txt ) > file2.txt
```

Then run the script again, but on `file2.txt` this time.

Comment: Thanks for the detaield answer. i'm at work but I'll try it later at home. thanks

Comment: It works - I developed it to rescue some wedding photos a wedding photographer friend had shot and his camera's memory card got corrupted. So I dumped the `/dev/sda` file and greppped for JPEG markers and found all 188 photos for him - in his case I just guessed each image was 10MB and Photoshop trimmed the rest off as he re-saved them afterwards.

Comment: well, this worked fine, but after all the files were not concatenated, I don't know what that mv did but it did not merge them...if it moved it somewhere I'm still to find where, perhaps it deleted them